# WPF. Calling referenced namespace from DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, multilingual

I have an assembly (technewlogic multilanguage, I just downloaded it) that I use as multilanguage provider in my WPF application.

Everything seems to work fine but datagrid headers.

I mean, when I do...

```
<TextBlock Text = "{ext:MultiLanguage Common.Id}" />
```

It just calls the function and shows the expected value.

But when I do...

```
<DataGrid Name="dg1"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"  
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding OneObservableCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentObject}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{ext:MultiLanguage Common.Id}" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

It doesn't even call the function and just show "Common.Id" as header text.

I've tried something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{ext:MultiLanguage Common.Id}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

With no results...

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you all.

Sergio.

Comment: Have you checked visual studios output for lines similar to "Cannot find source for binding with reference..."?

Comment: There's nothing on the output window...